# Mail storage method in dovecot

Tags: email, gmail, storage, postfix-mta, dovecot

Dovecot supports both `mbox` and `maildir` format to store emails. I searched its docs for storing all emails in `MySQL` database but i coundn't find it.

Is it possible to tell dovecot to store all outgoing and incoming emails in a database?

Storing emails in database can really be very flexible for searching emails for a keyworks in email etc..

How go **GMAIL** store its email? Is its based on **maildir** format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maildir is able to perform FTS within messages so you have to enable an appropriate plugin. Further reading is here: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/FTS

Also, mysql as well as other RDBMS are not well suited to manage email messages, so dovecot has its own indices and search mechanisms - fast and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get better I/O performance, consider using the sdbox format or mdbox. The first one is very similar to maildir, but have better index implementation. mdbox is similar to mbox, but can be splitted into several files and have a good index implementation too.

You can see more here: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/dbox